# Change .sbt path in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Is there way to change default `.sbt` path in scala-sbt project in IntelliJ.

IntelliJ version `13.0.2`

[image]

Because one of my machines takes network path for this and unable to resolve all the jars associate with that.

There is a way in below link to change the ivy path. Just wondering whether there is a same kind of approach here as well.

[Changing Ivy Cache Location for sbt projects in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845357/changing-ivy-cache-location-for-sbt-projects-in-intellij-idea)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to do but you can specify a sbt path in file/settings(ctrl+alt+s)/sbt then uncheck "use ide settings" and you can choose a path.

Comment: I don't see `use ide settings` in my IDEA version `13.0.2`

Comment: hum i have 13.1.3 but there must be somtehing similar under settings/sbt (the second if you have two sbt frame) like use project specific or somthing like that