# Why is intellij downloading project dependencies which are in ivy2/cache again

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, ivy

I've a **scala, sbt** project and I compiled the code using sbt-launcher's compile command. Sbt downloaded all the dependencies and compiled the project.But, when I imported the project into intelliJ,it again started downloading all the dependencies.I'm not sure why this is happening.Can someone explain more about this?

Comment: maybe you sellect  to download the sources or docs package

Comment: try setting the ivy cache location as answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845357/changing-ivy-cache-location-for-sbt-projects-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Is this reproducible for you when removing the artifacts from the cache, and is it indeed re-downloading the same artifacts, rather than sources/docs? In that case please file a bug report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL