# Intellij not picking dependencies from .ivy2 cache folder

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, build, sbt, ivy

I am using Intellij for scala project. I am using babun application for compiling/running/creating assembly jar for my project because in my organization, we can't use maven artifact repository and we have our own for downloading dependencies so I had setup proxy for it in babun(could not see such option for windows command application). Through babun, I downloaded all dependencies as defined in build.sbt and it got downloaded in `<USER_DIRECTORY>/.ivy2/cache`

Somehow, when I Synchronize my project in Intellij, it doesn't show up any dependencies(under `Project Structure->Project Settings->Modules->Dependencies tab`) and I get error in my code for all classes that are coming from dependency jars. It was working fine before but IDK what I did wrong suddenly :(

I also tried setting up VM argument `Dsbt.ivy.home=` but no help.

Also followed article - [Changing Ivy Cache Location for sbt projects in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845357/changing-ivy-cache-location-for-sbt-projects-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Is your project using building via sbt shell?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Thanks for reply, Yes it does compile

Comment: If you use chose a sbt shell import during prpject creation, then what you need to to to refresh project is open sbt panel and click refresh button. But If you are not using sbt for importing your project, then I don't know. I would try to remove .idea directory and import it all again.

Comment: does this happen for any project you try to import?